# installing a program returns error

Tags: ubuntu, make, installation

I'm installing lenstool which needs pgplot library so I got the source codes and followed [this](http://www.ucm.es/info/Astrof/software/howto/howto-pgplot.html) to install it I also ran one of it examples and it seemed to work. But when I try to make lenstool it returns this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpgplot
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Histogram] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/soroosh/soroosh/darkmatter/lenstool/lenstool_v6.7.1/utils'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

ubuntu 12.04 lts 64 bit. and I have installed pgplot in:

> /usr/local/src/pgplot

Is this a linking problem? Please help me with this.
tell me if other specifications are needed.

Comment: "ld" the dynamic library loader couldn't locate "lpgplot" library. So when you try to make "lenstool" you are missing "lpgplot". What do you mean by you've "installed" pgpplot in "/usr/local/src"?

Comment: I copied the files there and ran configure and make there also once it needs a destination directory which I set on the same folder

Comment: Run it like `LDFLAGS=-L/your/path/to/pgplot make`

Answer (score 0):

It was a linking problem, because of not standard path, linker couldn't find `pgplot` library. 
Solution is to add to `LDFLAGS`, parameter `-L`, which adds path to libraries.

`LDFLAGS=-L/your/path/to/pgplot make`